# subtract elements of two python list of different data types

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two python list having equal no of elements. i need to subtract only the int and float element of two list ignoring string elements.

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3.0, 'test', 6.5]
list_2 = [2, 3, 10.0, 'test', 12.5]
```

now third list should be the final diff of the elements of two lists

```
list_3 = [1, 1, 7.0, 'test', 6.0]
```

i am all-right in keeping the string value in list_3 of either of the list.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried this  list_3 = list(map(operator.sub, list_2 , list_1 )) but gets an error for str subtraction.

Comment: Was that unexpected? What did you try to avoid that issue?

Comment: Also, you should add more information about your lists and desired result like which list the third item belongs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using a list comprehension.

**Demo:**

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3.0, 'test', 6.5]
list_2 = [2, 3, 10.0, 'test', 12.5]

res = [v if (isinstance(i, str) or isinstance(v, str)) else (i-v) for i,v in zip(list_2, list_1)]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1, 7.0, 'test', 6.0]
```

Comment: what will if one of value is str and other float or integer?

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension will return the difference when both values are numerical, and will return the value from `list_1` if this is not the case:

```
from numbers import Number

list_1 = [1, 2, 3.0, 'test', 6.5]
list_2 = [2, 3, 10.0, 'test', 12.5]

list_3 = [y-x if isinstance(x,Number) and isinstance(y,Number) 
              else x for x,y in zip(list_1,list_2)]
```

```
print(list_3)
>>> [1, 1, 7.0, 'test', 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below approach.

```
>>> list_1 = [1, 2, 3.0, 'test', 6.5]
>>> list_2 = [2, 3, 10.0, 'test', 12.5]
>>>
>>> list_3 = [item2-item1 if type(item1) is int or type(item1) is float else item1 if item1 else item2 for item1, item2 in zip(list_1, list_2)]
>>>
>>> list_3
[1, 1, 7.0, 'test', 6.0]
>>>
```